# Proof Check: General solution Euler-lagrange Equation $\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+|y'|^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, calculus-of-variations

i'm just working through Calculus of variations problems and I'd like to cement my understanding and see if theres anywhere i'm going wrong. so if possibe could someone please provide a check on the workings. Thank you in advance.

> Find the general solution of the Euler-Lagrange equation associated with the function $$F(y) = \int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+|y'|^{2}} dx $$

1. Take the lagrangian to be $$\Lambda(x,y,y') = \sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+|y'|^{2}} $$
2. then the Euler-Lagrange equation is $$\frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial y} - \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial y'} = 0$$
3. Substituting $$\frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial y} = 0$$ with $$\frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial y'} = \frac{y'\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{1+y'^{2}}} $$ 
   then $$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial y'} = \frac{2xy'' + y'[1+y'^2]}{2x(1+y'^2)^{3/2}} \implies$$
   $$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial y'} - \frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial y} = \frac{2xy'' + y'[1+y'^2]}{2x(1+y'^2)^{3/2}} = 0$$
4. substitute $y' = v \implies y'' = v'$ and we have $$\frac{2xv' + v[1+v^2]}{2x(1+v^2)^{3/2}} = 0 \implies$$
   $$\frac{v'}{(1+v^2)^{3/2}} = \frac{-v[1+v^{2}]}{2x(1+v^2)^{3/2}} \implies$$
   $$v' = \frac{-v[1+v^{2}]}{2x} \implies$$
   $$2 \frac{dv}{dx} = \frac{-v[1+v^{2}]}{2x} \implies$$
   $$2 \frac{dv}{-v(1+v^2)} = \frac{dx}{x} \implies$$
   $$ln(v^{2}+1)-2ln(v)=ln x+c \implies$$
   $$ ln \frac{v^{2}+1}{v^2} = ln x + c \implies$$
   $$1 + \frac{1}{v^2} = e^{c}x \implies$$
   $$ v = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{xe^{c}-1}} \implies$$
   $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{xe^{c}-1}} \implies$$
   $$y = \pm \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{xe^{c}-1}} = \pm \frac{2 \sqrt{xe^{c}-1}}{e^{c}} + C$$
   As a general solution:

If there's any mistakes please, point them out. I appreciate it greatly and thanks for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your function doesn't depend on $y$ then Euler-Lagrange equation is realy simple.
You can rewrite this as $\frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial y'}=C$

Comment: Using your suggestion (which i admittedly missed) i get $$y(x) = \pm 2C\sqrt{x- C^{2}} + C_2 $$ which admittedly looks very similiar.